# Is HP deskjet F4488 supported?

Tags: drivers, printing, hp

Is HP deskjet F4488 supported by Ubuntu 11.10.
if yes how to interface it and in not why not.?

Answer (score 3):

[According to HP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/deskjet_aio/deskjet_f4400_series.html), this printer has been supported using the `hplip` package since v3.9.6. [According to the `hplip` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&searchon=names&keywords=hplip) on launchpad, this printer has been supported since 10.04.

You can install `hplip` from the Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

Then connect your printer.

If necessary, you can add your printer via the Dash - printer icon - you can select the driver manually i.e.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If selecting the driver from the cups interface does not work.

Download and install HPLIP directly from the HP OPEN SOURCE website. http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html

Click on DOWNLOAD HPLIP. Find the downloaded file and right click on it and select PERMISSIONS. Select MAKE EXECUTABLE. Click OK.

Right click on the file again and select OPEN then EXECUTE. Follow the instuctions.

*Reason it works is mainly because it detects and installs dependencies that the apt-get or software center version won't.

Answer (score -3):

This is actually not really an Ubuntu question.  Printer drivers are supplied by the printer manufacturer - in this case HP.  There is also a well supported package for Ubuntu called 'hplip' which gets most HP printers working.  Check this out, and also go to the HP website and search for your printer.

Comment: Questions about third-party software that runs on Ubuntu, including third-party drivers, are still considered to be about Ubuntu and are on topic for AskUbuntu.com.